Partial differential equation with wavy walls
I have the following boundary value problems.
$$\frac{h^3}{3}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2}+h^2\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial t};~~p(t)=0~~\text{at}~~x=0,~p(t)=0~~\text{at}~~x=1;$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x};~~\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0~~\text{at}~~y=0,~u=0~~\text{at}~~y=h;$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x};~~v=\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}~~\text{at}~~y=h.$$
Here $p=p(x,t)$, $h=h(x,t)$, $u=u(x,y,t)$ and $v=v(x,y,t)$ in which $x,~y$ are space variables and $t$ is time variable.\
The expression of $h(x,t)$ is given by $h(x,t)=1-\epsilon \cos^2(x-t)$. \
I am trying to solve the first equations at $t=0.25$ and remaining equation at $t=0.25,~x=0.35$ when $\epsilon=0.1$.
I am trying with the following codes using NDSolve.
epsilon = 0.1;
St=1.0
t = 0.25;
h = 1.0 - (epsilon*Cos[2.0*pi*St*(x - t)]);
hdt = -(epsilon*2.0*pi*St*Sin[2.0*pi*St*(x - t)]);
hdx = (epsilon*2.0*pi*St*Sin[2.0*pi*St*(x - t)]);
eq1 = {(h^3/3.0)*p''[x] + (h^2*hdx)*p'[x] == hdt};
bc1 = {p[0.0] == 0.0, p[1.0] == 0.0};
s1 = NDSolve[Join[eq1, bc1], p, {x, 0.0, 1}];
(*x=0.35;
eq2={u''[y]==p'[x]};
bc2={u'[0]==0.0,u[h]==0.0};
eq3={v'[y]==-u'[x]};
bc3={v[h]==hdt};
s2=NDSolve[Join[eq2,bc2],u,{y,0.0,h}];*)
Plot[Evaluate[p'[x] /. s1], {x, 0.0, 1.0}, PlotRange -> All]

I got the desired plot for $p'(x)$ vs $x$ for given $t$ as follows.

Now I want to solve other two equations and plot $u$ vs $y$ and $v$ vs $y$ for given values of $x$ and $t$. Seeking help on how to define second and third equation and solve all the equations simultaneously  using NDSolve.
